# R - Range of number sequences, or how can I get the reverse of 1:10

Tags: r, range, seq

I can't seem to find an elegant solution to finding ranges. For me, it would come down to this:

```
> seq(1:10)
  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

I would like to get the reverse:

```
function(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
result 1:10
```

Real world problem is that I have 1200 indices, some are 0, some are 1:

```
c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1)
```

And I would like the ranges/coordinates within the vector for each set of 0s and 1s.

Comment: Something like `rle(your_vector)`?

Comment: Can you give the sample output based on the `0` & `1` index you mentioned?

Comment: `parse(text=deparse(1:10))[[1]]`

Comment: rle() was what I was looking for! Sorry for the convoluted question - MKRs solution works for the first part of the question.

Comment: Is this similar to what you want? `y <- rle(x);vec_pos <- paste0(cumsum(c(1, head(y[[1]], - 1))),":", cumsum(y[[1]]));setNames(vec_pos, y[[2]])`

Answer (score 4):

Will this simple solution work?

```
> rev(seq(1:10))
 [1] 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1

> range(seq(1:10))
[1]  1 10
```

Comment: That's what I thought at first based on the title, but the body of the question shows they want something else

Comment: @duckmayr Sorry. I had added only half part of solution. Rest I have added now.