# reverse loop interation in R like in Python

Tags: python, r

here is my python loop code with output

```
peaks =range(2,10)
for i in range(len(peaks) - 1, -1, -1):
print(i)

# 7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0
```

but i do not know how to do this with R

suggest me please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R - Range of number sequences, or how can I get the reverse of 1:10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48411151/r-range-of-number-sequences-or-how-can-i-get-the-reverse-of-110)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Sosel. Nevertheless, here is working code:

```
peaks = 2:9
for(i in rev(0:(length(peaks)-1))) print(i)
```

Comment: thanks man , but here we take peaks =(2:9) , actually it (2:10) , how can we solve it

Comment: @Jose: In R, unlike Python, `2:n` means all the numbers from `2`  to `n`, including both 2 and n.

Comment: gotcha , but here we set it manually , in my case it varies every time, how can i do that?

Comment: that range is coming directly, i just have to pass peak

Answer (score 1):

in R

```
peaks <- c(2:10)
l <- length(peaks)
result <- l - peaks
result[result > 0]
```

returns

```
7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

if you nedd a for loop, you can use this:

```
for(p in peaks){ifelse(l-p >= 0, print(l-p), NA)}
```

Comment: thanks , can you please do this with For loop , that is what i want

Comment: kindly check the comment of above ans as well

Comment: and there is  7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0